# How to catch event log clearing attempt?

Tags: c#, event-log

Is it possible somehow to catch attempt to clean the event log? So that I can cancel that attempt or make an archive and only then allow to clear the log. Or if it's not possible to catch such event, maybe there are other ways to force user to make only clearing with archiving? (Using .Net 3.5, Windows 7) 
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can control access for the event log. There are many access levels. You can use [EventLogPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogpermission.aspx) Class. You can specify access levels by using

`public enum EventLogPermissionAccess { Write };`

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, which is about sort of handling event of cleaning log, but not restricting doing that.